# How to improve performance of soap web service consuming and parsing the soap data using KSOAP2 in android?

Tags: android, performance, ksoap2

I am using`KSOAP2` library in my `Android` project to connect remote `SOAP web services` developed in `.NET` framework. KSOAP2 library parsing soap data very slow when compared with `iphone` soap `parsing`. Also some times, when i debugging the `server communication` in my android project, web service is calling more than one time even if the programming logic written only once. Can any one help me how can i improve the performance of KSOAP2 web service calling and parsing the data like iphone in my android project.

Answer (score 0):

Ksoap performance seems quite sufficient in my use cases. Did you try to debug/profile your parsing and code. Might well be that something else you do is the culprit.

Is there anything special about your response? Very large? Has binary in it?

Comment: for small responses also it is getting very slow compared with iphone.

Comment: You got any evidence or test cases that proof that? Once thing for example is that you need to switch debug off for good performance.

Comment: yes, when i am moving app to production release i am switching off the debug mode.